# Custom Title for Email in Android?

Tags: android, email

I have working with email option. i can send the Email using the intent chooser method. by this i can get the default email compose window with the title of "Compose". i want to change and customize this. is there any possible to do the Feature_Custom_Title option for it? Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not your application, so you are limited to what configuration you can pass via `Intent` extras. I do not believe there is an extra to change the title.